# App crashes on launch due to Spotify issue

Tags: ios, iphone, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

We are working on a project where we are fetching feeds from Spotify. We have integrated Spotify library in the same. The app was rejected by MFI approval process due to app launch crash issue. We are stuck here. Its really urgent and we appreciate some quick help.

We are getting a app crash error when app launches. We are calling a method, which might be the reason of the crash but we are not sure.

```
- (void)clearKeychain {
  for( NSString *serviceName in @[@"rdio",@"spotify",@"spotifyUsername",@"muzik"]) {
    DDLogVerbose(@"removing keychain entry for service = %@", serviceName);
    [MZUserManager removeTokenForService:serviceName];
  }

MZSpotifyService *spotify = (MZSpotifyService*)[[MZDataManager sharedManager] serviceWithName:[MZSpotifyService shortName]];
  [spotify.sessionManager logout];

  [MZRdioService rdio].delegate = nil;
  [[MZRdioService rdio] logout];
}

---------------------------------

- (MZBaseService *)serviceWithName:(NSString *)serviceName
{
    NSLog(@"active services : \n %@",_activeServices);
  return _activeServices[serviceName];
}

---------------------------------------

- (void)logout {
  [[SPSession sharedSession] logout:^{
    DDLogVerbose(@"logged out from spotify");
  }];
}
```

Below are the logs

```
2013-10-31 15:43:54 -0700 muzik[297] <Warning> *** Assertion failure in NSString* base::deviceIdFromKeychain()(), /Users/spotify-buildagent/buildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/base/_apple/_ios/os_ios.mm:287
2013-10-31 15:43:54 -0700 muzik[297] <Error> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Keychain error when fetching device ID, nonrecoverable'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e265e8b 0x385ca6c7 0x2e265d5d 0x2ec0e29b 0x2ea90f 0x2eaee5 0x2e7bb3 0x1a618d 0x1a545d 0x2e230f55 0x2e2302cf 0x2e22ebd5 0x2e199541 0x2e1dd1ab 0x1a55a1 0x2ec49dc7 0x38be0c5d 0x38be0bcf 0x38bdecd0)
```

*Detail logs are [uploaded here](https://skydrive.live.com/?mkt=en-IN#cid=83FB4271DB03ED40&id=83FB4271DB03ED40!593) (skydive)*

**Full Crash Logs shared by MFI**

```
Date/Time:           2013-10-31 15:43:54.065 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.2 (11A501)
UDID:                41ab058a88eb7c1c3976828019bdfa0bd5edae22
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  7

Filtered syslog:
2013-10-31 15:43:52 -0700 muzik[297] <Warning> Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_120_4.2.4] 
2013-10-31 15:43:53 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:53 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:53 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:53 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:53 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:53 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:53 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:54 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:54 -0700 muzik[297] <Error>  SecOSStatusWith error:[-34018] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.osstatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements))
2013-10-31 15:43:54 -0700 muzik[297] <Warning> *** Assertion failure in NSString* base::deviceIdFromKeychain()(), /Users/spotify-buildagent/buildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/base/_apple/_ios/os_ios.mm:287
2013-10-31 15:43:54 -0700 muzik[297] <Error> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Keychain error when fetching device ID, nonrecoverable'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e265e8b 0x385ca6c7 0x2e265d5d 0x2ec0e29b 0x2ea90f 0x2eaee5 0x2e7bb3 0x1a618d 0x1a545d 0x2e230f55 0x2e2302cf 0x2e22ebd5 0x2e199541 0x2e1dd1ab 0x1a55a1 0x2ec49dc7 0x38be0c5d 0x38be0bcf 0x38bdecd0)
```

Comment: Do you have a correct appkey?

Comment: Yes it is a valid key, we are able to run the app on most of the device, but it is causing an issue for the MFI is HongKong location only. We tried to run the app via testfligth in India and US regions and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes it is a valid key, we are able to run the app on most of the device, but it is causing an issue for the MFI is HongKong location only. We tried to run the app via testflight in India and US regions and it works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

The important error is here:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements)

Now, as to why you're triggering it, I don't know. Try Googling that specific error — it's not Spotify-specific.

However, it looks like you're storing Spotify credentials in the Keychain, and you might be triggering the problem by clearing stuff from the Keychain. Unfortunately, "We are calling a method" isn't helpful information.

Now, you shouldn't be storing Spotify credentials in the Keychain. DEFINITELY not user passwords — that's a breach of the ToS. CocoaLibSpotify gives you token that are safe to store in `NSUserDefaults`.

You can find an example of how to store Spotify credentials properly in the "Empty CocoaLibSpotify" sample project that ships with the library.

Also, try testing your archive builds before submitting them to the App Store. There's no reason this shouldn't be triggering for you locally if it's happening during review.